# samba username case issue in samba 4.x

Tags: networking, server, samba, file-sharing

I have a problem with a samba service on my server. It's began since ubuntu have switched to samba 4.x in their distributions and continues til last one 15.04.

I have a user `ag` on my server and user `AG` on a Windows 7 box. In samba 3.x everything worked fine but in samba 4.x I've got some funny username mismatch issue.

I observe following behavior: When I login from Windows host I type a username `ag` (or `AG` it does not matter) and a password. Samba server rejects me for a first time but lets me in on second try. Actually, the same behavior show Linux and Mac OSX clients too, so it's not a Windows issue. I can simulate this from linux console following way:

```
nas@AGStorage:~$ smbclient -U AG //agvault/backup
Enter AG's password:
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_NO_MEMORY
nas@AGStorage:~$ smbclient -U AG //agvault/backup
Enter AG's password:
Domain=[HOME] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 4.1.13-Ubuntu]
smb: \> q
```

I tried to analyze the behavior with Wireshark and it shows clear that Windows tries first with `AG` (remember the user name in Windows is `AG`) and gets error, then comes with `ag` second time and gets Ok from samba server.

When I simulate the login with `ag` it lets in with a single try:

```
nas@AGStorage:~$ smbclient -U ag //agvault/backup
Enter ag's password:
Domain=[HOME] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 4.1.13-Ubuntu]
smb: \> q
```

I've tried suggested in internet solution: Adding a line `username map = /etc/samba/usermap.txt` to my `smb.conf` with `ag = AG` inside of mentioned `usermap.txt` but it does not work in my case.

How can I fix this inconsistent behavior of samba server? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've just noticed It might be not a user name case issue, but some different case, because it sometimes rejects me with ag (small) too.

    nas@AGStorage:~$ smbclient -U ag //agvault/backup  
    Enter ag's password:  
    session setup failed: NT_STATUS_NO_MEMORY  
    nas@AGStorage:~$ smbclient -U ag //agvault/backup  
    Enter ag's password:  
    Domain=[HOME] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 4.1.13-Ubuntu]  
    smb: \> q

Answer (score 1):

Following command helps a lot:

```
sudo service winbind stop
```

Somehow (I do not know exactly how) my samba server is missconfigured to talk to `winbind` even if it has a `standalone server` role. This seams to cause a misscommunication with `winbind` and `NT_STATUS_NO_MEMORY` failure on first login.

Have fun ppl!